# Sprint Integration : how to use 2 Chain and 2 parallel in 1 single gateway

Tags: java, spring, integration

I am trying to do 2 services in chain, and after that I want 2 services in parallel. For this I am returning list from transformer after 2nd chain service and used splitter and router for splitting list. I have added aggregate channel. In aggregate channel I am getting only response of parallel services.

PFB code:

```
<int:channel id="ResultChannel" />

<int:aggregator input-channel="AggrChannel" method="aggregate" output-channel="ResultChannel" expire-groups-upon-completion="true" release-strategy-expression="size() == 4" > 
    <bean class="com.si.userprofiles.transformer.Transformer" />
</int:aggregator>


<int:chain input-channel="req_1" output-channel="resp_1">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="SOAPAction" value="getSOAPAction"></int:header>
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/xml"></int:header>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="eai_1" url="${EAI.API.url}" http-method="POST" request-factory="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8">
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="resp_1" task-executor="executor" apply-sequence="true" />    
<int:bridge input-channel="resp_1" output-channel="AggrChannel" />  



<int:transformer method="transform_1" input-channel="resp_1" output-channel="req_2"> 
    <bean class="com.si.userprofiles.transformer.Transformer" />
</int:transformer>

<int:chain input-channel="req_2" output-channel="resp_2">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
        <int:header name="Authorization" value="${EAI.CacheService.Authorization}"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="eai_2" url="${EAI.API2.url}" http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" request-factory="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"
        charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="2000"> 
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="resp_2" task-executor="executor" apply-sequence="true" />

<int:bridge input-channel="resp_2" output-channel="AggrChannel" />

<int:transformer method="transform_2" input-channel="resp_2" output-channel="req_parallel">
    <bean class="com.si.userprofiles.transformer.Transformer" />
</int:transformer>


<bean id="mq1ConnFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType" value="${EAI.API3.transportType}" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="${EAI.API3.queueManager}" />
    <property name="hostName" value="${EAI.API3.hostName}" />
    <property name="port" value="${EAI.API3.port}" />
    <property name="channel" value="${EAI.API3.channel}" />
</bean>
<bean id="mq1ReqQ" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${EAI.API3.Input.MQName}" />
</bean>
<bean id="mq1RespQ" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${EAI.API3.Output.MQName}" />
</bean>


<bean id="mq2ConnFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="Q manager name" />
    <property name="hostName" value="ip" />
    <property name="port" value="port" />
    <property name="channel" value="channel name" />
</bean>
<bean id="mq2ReqQ" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="request Q name" />
</bean>
<bean id="mq2RespQ" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="Resp Q name" />
</bean>
<!-- <int:chain input-channel="req_3" output-channel="AggrChannel">
    <int-jms:outbound-gateway id="eai_3" connection-factory="ConnFactory" request-destination="mq1ReqQ" reply-timeout="${EAI.API3.reply-timeout}" reply-destination="mq1RespQ">
    </int-jms:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain> -->

<!-- start of parallel -->


<int:splitter id="msgSplitter" input-channel="req_parallel"
    method="split" output-channel="RoutingChannel">
    <bean class="com.si.fm.splitter.MessageSplitter"></bean>
</int:splitter>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="RoutingChannel"
    header-name="routingHeader" > <!-- default-output-channel="AggrChannel" -->
    <int:mapping value="1" channel="req_3" />
    <int:mapping value="2" channel="req_4" />
</int:header-value-router>


<int:channel id="RoutingChannel" />



<int:chain input-channel="req_3" output-channel="resp_3">
    <int-jms:outbound-gateway id="eai_3" connection-factory="mq1ConnFactory" request-destination="mq1ReqQ" reply-timeout="${EAI.API3.reply-timeout}" reply-destination="mq1RespQ">
    </int-jms:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="resp_3" task-executor="executor" apply-sequence="true" />    

<int:bridge input-channel="resp_3" output-channel="AggrChannel" /> 


<int:chain input-channel="req_4" output-channel="resp_4">
    <int-jms:outbound-gateway id="eai_4" connection-factory="mq2ConnFactory" request-destination="mq2ReqQ" reply-timeout="${EAI.API4.reply-timeout}" reply-destination="mq2RespQ">
    </int-jms:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="req_4" task-executor="executor" apply-sequence="true" /> 
    <int:bridge input-channel="resp_4" output-channel="AggrChannel" /> 

<!-- end of parallel -->
```

Comment: Can you tell us what all have you tried? Also, include code you have written. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask more constructively.

Comment: @harshavmb I tried this code, I also tried removing release strategy